# Importing Provider from react-redux 5.0.5 causes blank screen in react-native

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native

No matter I use Provider in my rendering code or not, I get a blank screen. Then, I found that even I just import Provider from react-redux , I will get a blank screen. But if I comment out the `import { Provider } from 'react-redux'`, the apps work sucessfully.

As suggested by the official repo, I have checked there is no duplicate react module installed with `npm ls react` and the version of react-redux is above 5, which should be working with react-native.

How should I solve the problem?
Thanks.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
} from 'react-native';

import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Chat from './pages/Chat';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key='root' style={{paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 64 : 54}}>
                    <Scene key='home' title='Home' component={Home}/>
                    <Scene key='chat' title='Chat' component={Chat}/>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "async-storage": "^0.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "cookie": "^0.3.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.0.1",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.11",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.1.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.3",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^3.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "0.0.10",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.21",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^4.9.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "^1.4.0",
    "superagent": "^3.6.0",
    "validator": "^8.2.0",
    "webpack-isomorphic-tools": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use react's component. Look below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

use the react-redux for the connect like

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```

and

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {sampleActionHere})(ComponentsName)
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think there is no difference between extending React.Component and Component.  And, I only use connect for lower level components (such as Home and Chat in my example).
Btw, it turns out that I only have to update react-redux to solve my problems. 
Thanks.

Comment: i am using connect for lower level as well. But i am only using component from react since there is no point to use react-redux for this. Glad you fixed it. cheers !

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem by upgrading react-redux to 5.0.6.